# Ionic envio de arquivo

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um app ionic onde quero enviar um arquivo (na realidade uma foto ), esse tipo de request tentei em get, porem não deu certo...
Como posso arrumar ? (o problema é envio via get ?
O meu arquivo php é este :

```html
  <?php
  $foto = $_FILES['img']['name']; // nome do arquivo
  $uploaddir = '';
  $dirArquivo = $uploaddir . $foto;
  if(file_exists($dirArquivo) == true) {header ('location: ../admCreateVagas.php?msg=ERRO:ARQUIVO_NAO_ENVIADO_ja_existe_mude_o_nome_e_tente_novamente');} else {
   $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['img']['name'];
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
   }else{ print_r($_FILES); echo "Arquivo não enviado"; header ('location: ../admCreateVagas.php?msg=ERRO:ARQUIVO_NAO_ENVIADO');}
   
   }

 

?>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Então Ionic como diz o site deles só aceita `HTML, CSS and JS`, então você não vai conseguir rodar PHP dentro do seu APP, das duas, uma ou vc faz upload para dentro do proprio aparelho usando algum componente, ou vc fz upload pra um server externo ai tera que mistura uma boa dose de JS a uma programação extra ... [veja esse exemplo](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/upload-files-remote-server-using-ionic-framework/).

Comment: SK15 eu sei que o ionic nâ trabalha com php, esse arquivo é o que esta no server .... Gostaria de saber se eu enviar o request via post do campo form ele aceitaria ? e se sim como faço o request post passando o camo file ? Caso nâo como fazer para enviar ?